# Upload multiple files to FTP Server from iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios, upload, ftp

For a new project I need to upload some html and jpeg files from iPhone to a FTP Server.

I examined Apples SimpleFTPSample and managed to upload a file.

But what is the correct way to upload more than *one* file? Do I have to repeat the whole process with creating input- and output streams with username and password for each file or is there a simpler way?

Thank you for any hint!

Comment: That's it. Anyway, the CFFTPStream may be too low-level. Take a look in libcurl, which makes it much easier. It will cache the connection and a has handful variety of options. One question though, to other developers: is it available in iOS?

Comment: Ok, I did it by running a loop with a modified version of the SimpleFTPSample code and managed to upload multiple files.